# asp.net core razor pages view components

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to make some logic to use view component within asp.net core razor pages. 
Following here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components and my test project at https://github.com/azizkazdal/aspnetcorerazorpages/tree/master/ViewComponent 
can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? 
Made a simple logic but could not worked it

Comment: what have you done and what error/issue are you having ? Can you please provide more details like  -  what are you trying to achieve, what have done so far, what is the error/exception/issue you are facing ? clarity in your question will help others to understand your problem clearly and provide answer ? Thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

I have not got any issue just was taking not content from view component.
then I wrote aspnet github channel and they send me below answer

**Component.InvokeAsync returns an IHtmlContent: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/IViewComponentHelper.cs#L26. The returned value needs to be written to the output, like the second instance, for the view component's content to appear in the output.**

So I changed the code like as below

@await Component.InvokeAsync("DeleteModal", new { name = "Default", item = Model.ViewModel.DeleteModalViewModel })

I was coding Component.Invoke methods as below

```
@{
@await Component.InvokeAsync("DeleteModal", new { name = "Default", item = Model.ViewModel.DeleteModalViewModel })
}
```

and this worked fine.

Comment: in addtion,
classic core mvc application both work fine